# How the select the date part from in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query in Postegre SQL:

```
SELECT * from myTable 
WHERE date(myTimeStampColumn) = '2019-01-01'
```

Since I switched to SQL, I use either this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE (
        SELECT CONVERT(date, myDateTimeColumn)
      ) = '2019-01-01'
```

or this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE date(myDateTimeColumn) > '2019-01-01'
  AND
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE date(myDateTimeColumn) < '2019-01-02'
```

Is there a faster/simpler way to select the date part of datetime column in sqlserver ?

Comment: No need for `SELECT`; `WHERE CONVERT(date, myDateTimeColumn) ='2019-01-01'` should do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the query as below

```
select * from myTable where CONVERT(date, myDateTimeColumn) = '2019-01-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

Following query is equivalent to what you were writing in `PostgreSQL`

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE CAST(myTimeStampColumn AS DATE)='2019-01-01'
```

As suggested by  Dan Guzman, above query is **non-SARGable**, so will not get the benefit of indexes.

For better performance you can write same query like following.

```
 SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE
 myTimeStampColumn >= '2019-01-01' AND myTimeStampColumn < '2019-01-02'
```

Comment: The CAST will preclude an index seek, requiring a full table scan. More verbose but more efficient is `myTimeStampColumn >= '2019-01-01' AND myTimeStampColumn < '2019-01-02'`.